# The ratio of number of edges to the sum of vertices and edges of a graph.

Tags: graph-theory, ratio, graph-connectivity

The ratio of number of edges to the number of vertices of a graph is called its beta index (it is a measure of the graph  connectivity).  Now, i want to use a term which is the ratio of number of edges to the sum of vertices and edges of a graph (is this ratio has a name already?). As per my observations, the numerical value of this ratio of a graph $G$ is always less than or equal to its subgraphs. My questions are:

> What is call this ratio?

> Is my observation of the numerical value of this ratio of a graph $G$ being always less than or equal to its subgraphs correct?

**Edit:** Discrete graph, empty graph and null graph are excluded here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this does not always hold. We can find graphs where your ratio is arbitrarily close to $1$: for example, a complete graph with $n$ vertices has a ratio of
$$
   \frac{\binom n2}{n + \binom n2} = \frac{n-1}{n+1} = 1 - \frac2{n+1}.
$$
On the other hand, you can take a subgraph consisting of, for example, two adjacent vertices and the edge between them. Here, the ratio is just $\frac{1}{2+1} = \frac13$.

---

Your ratio does not have a name, but it's a function of your "beta index": if a graph has $v$ vertices, $e$ edges, and beta index $\beta = \frac ev$, then the ratio $\frac{e}{v+e}$ is equal to $\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}$. It can also be found in terms of a more well-known quantity, the average degree: if a graph has average degree $d$, then it has beta index $\frac12d$, so your ratio is $\frac{d}{d+2}$.

In particular, it's an increasing function of both values, so if you take any graph $G$ and a subgraph $H$ with a smaller average degree, then the same relation will hold between their ratios: we'll have $\frac{e(G)}{v(G)+e(G)} > \frac{e(H)}{v(H) + e(H)}$.

Comment: Beta index should be $\beta=\frac{e}{v}$

Comment: Fixed! That's what I used to go from $\frac{e}{v+e}$ to $\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}$, I just made a typo.

Comment: The sequence $\frac{e(G)}{v(G)+e(G)} > \frac{e(H)}{v(H) + e(H)}$ etc. is really i am looking for. Is there any formal proof of such formulations that i may cite?

Comment: I mean, there's no consistent rule about which way it will go. For some subgraphs, the ratio might be bigger, and for others, it might be smaller.

Comment: It is noted. But i hope atleast the ratio will increase consistently with subsequent sub graphs with smaller average degrees.

Comment: Also, do you also mean that there is no way to compare the connectivity of a graph and its subgraphs in consistant manner?

Comment: Well, if you have a specific graph and subgraph in mind, you can compute the ratios for both. I mean that in general, you can't predict it. (Also, your ratio will *decrease* with smaller average degree, not increase.)

Comment: uff! Wrongly typed 'increase'. Thanks.